# How to read a file using when applying a custom hash function

Tags: java, data-structures, netbeans, hash, linked-list

Currently I am attempting to make a Question/Answer game using with data structures. However when I try to read in a text file I get an arrayoutofbounds exception. Should I adjust my hash or am I reading the file wrong.

My Node class is a class called Questions. It contains a String "key" which will be the question.....a Sting value which will be the answer. My intention is to create a GIU application. But I dont seem to get past reading my text file.

```
 public QuizBox() {
        initComponents();
        populateQuestions();
  
    }

    public void populateQuestions() {
        File questionFile = new File("C:\\Users\\jb\\Desktop\\QuestionAnswerSheet.txt");
        QuestionsHash ques = new QuestionsHash(15);

        try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(questionFile);
            QuestionsHash qa = new QuestionsHash(15);
            while (input.hasNext()) {
               String line = input.nextLine();
               ques.get(line);
                
                System.out.println(line.toString());
            }
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    } 

public class QuestionsHash<T> {
    Questions[] questionsHash;
    int size;
    
    public QuestionsHash(int size){
        this.size=size;
        questionsHash=new Questions[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
           questionsHash[i]=new Questions(); 
        }
    }
        
      int getHash(String key){
         int hash=0;
         int g=3;
          for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
              hash +=  key.charAt(i) * g;
              g=g+2;
          }
          
        return hash;
    }
    
    public void put(String key, String value){
        int hashIndex=getHash(key);
        Questions arrayValue= questionsHash[hashIndex];
        Questions newItem = new Questions(key, value);
        newItem.next = arrayValue.next;
        arrayValue.next = newItem;
    }
    
    public T get(String key){
        T value = null;
        int hashIndex=getHash(key);
        Questions arrayValue= questionsHash[hashIndex];
        while(arrayValue != null){
        if(arrayValue.getKey()==key){
        value=(T) arrayValue.next;
        break;
        }
        arrayValue=arrayValue.next;
    }    
        return value;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full error. This line is your main issue `int hashIndex=getHash(key);` At a glance, it appears that you are trying to use the hash as an index of the `questionsHash` array, and the hash is larger than 14 (which causes an out of bounds error). And this is caused by returning a number over 14 from your `getHash` method, specifically what happens when the first character in the line/key is 8 and your multiply it by 3 in your getHash method....? Why are you using the hash value as an array index?

Comment: Yeah I just noticed there is where I am getting the error. I though using it as an index would assist with collisions. Still kind of new to this as you may suspect and trying to get an understanding of it.